# Sending class field meta data in message

Tags: java, json, reflection, jackson, meta

Has anyone come across this issue in `jackson JSON` - somehow the `JSON` is including each of my class' field types, and other meta data I'm not interested in and as such the data being sent is huge!

E.g. this is one record:

```
{
    "queue": "H",
    "internalStatus": "New",
    "id": "50030386",
    "screenDescription": "Test Case 1",

}
},
"fields": [
{
    "name": "id",
    "type": "java.lang.Integer",
    "modifiers": 2,
    "annotations": [

    ],
    "declaredAnnotations": [

    ],
    "declaringClass": "com.me.Charge",
    "synthetic": false,
    "genericType": "java.lang.Integer",
    "enumConstant": false,
    "accessible": false
},
{
    "name": "screenDescription",
    "type": "java.lang.String",
    "modifiers": 2,
    "annotations": [

    ],
    "declaredAnnotations": [

    ],
    "declaringClass": "com.me.Charge",
    "synthetic": false,
    "genericType": "java.lang.String",
    "enumConstant": false,
    "accessible": false
},
{
    "name": "internalStatus",
    "type": "java.lang.String",
    "modifiers": 2,
    "annotations": [

    ],
    "declaredAnnotations": [

    ],
    "declaringClass": "com.me.Charge",
    "synthetic": false,
    "genericType": "java.lang.String",
    "enumConstant": false,
    "accessible": false
},
{
    "name": "queue",
    "type": "java.lang.String",
    "modifiers": 2,
    "annotations": [

    ],
    "declaredAnnotations": [

    ],
    "declaringClass": "com.me.Charge",
    "synthetic": false,
    "genericType": "java.lang.String",
    "enumConstant": false,
    "accessible": false
},
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Stephen

Comment: Can we see the class you're trying to serialise ?

Comment: this normal behaviour for polymorphic types. if you could include what jackson version you use, we could tell you how to get rid of it

Answer (score 0):

Check your code for setting

```
objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(...)
```

to some value...